# Jquery só valida um elemento de vários

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de mostrar a mensagem do required em cada elemento do input além de realizar a verificação em cada par de checkbox e input text, mas ela só está ocorrendo no primeiro input que estou dando foco.

```
    <html>
    <head>  
    <script src="/jscss/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jscss/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {

//Método para verificar as notas com uso de expressão regular
$.validator.addMethod("verifica_media", function(value, element) {  
return   ((/^(((([1]{1}[0]{1})\.([0]{1}))|((([0_]{1})(\d){1}))\.(\d{1})))?$/i.test(value) && !($('.Checkconceito').is(":checked"))) || ((this.optional(element)) && ($('.Checkconceito').is(":checked"))));  
}, "Por favor entre com uma nota válida ou o conceito F.");

$(".conceito").validate({
// Define as regras
    debug: true,
    rules:{
        media:{
            verifica_media: true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        media:{
            required: "Digite uma média válida (valores entre 0.0 e 10.0"
        }
    }
        }); 

    }); 
    </script> 
    <script src="/jscss/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $(".conceito").mask("99.9");        
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body><form id="formularioContato" method="post">

    <div align="center">
    <ul>
<li>
<label>Nota:</label><input type="text" id="nota" name="nota" class="conceito"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="notaf" name="notaf" value="notaf" class="Checkconceito">Nota F
<br />
</li>
<li>
<label>Nota:</label><input type="text" size="4" id="nota" name="nota" class="conceito"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="notaf" name="notaf" value="notaf" class="Checkconceito">Nota F
<br />
</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o HTML gerado?

Comment: Não posso infelizmente mas o problema acredito eu está no validator, ele não compreende que estou em cada input, ele só intepreta o primeiro que dou foco.

Comment: Tentei interpretar seu código e gerar o HTML manualmente, não consegui, o que impossibilitou de testar o seu código. Use dados inventados e/ou separe só a parte do código que envolve o validador.

Comment: alterei para um teste em html que gera basicamente o mesmo caso.

Comment: Criei um bin baseado no seu código: http://jsbin.com/fekikinu/1/edit

Comment: Não seria um problema com os IDs não poderia ter dois mesmos ids

Comment: Parece que você não está usando o plugin corretamente: ele valida `<form>`s e não `<input>`s. Como o seletor está errado o jQuery não encontra as variáveis corretas e o código falha.

Comment: O validator pega pelo name e não pelo id, eu tinha retirado os id's e mesmo assim continua igual.

Comment: @SamirBraga Quanto aos IDs ele está gerando esse código, só ele usar algo como `id="notaf-1"`.

Comment: Alterei o seletor no bin para selecionar o formulário e nenhum erro apareceu no console. Ainda há um problema: o método `verifica_media` não verifica se o checkbox que está relacionado a `input` que está sendo validada, mas isso é fácil de arrumar.

Comment: Pronto! A última versão do bin funciona para qualquer número de elementos, verificando elementos com a classe `.conceito`. Ele ainda verifica pelo checkbox próximo ao input. É isso o que procurava?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".conceito").validate({...})
```

O [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) é usado em elementos `<input>`, porém em elementos `<form>`. Isso é o que causava erros no console pois o plugin não encontrava as configurações definidas quando validava, devido aos elementos usados.

```
$("#formularioContato").validate({...})
```

Essa é a maneira correta de se usar o plugin, uma vez que dessa forma ele estará validando o formulário.

```
media:{
  verifica_media: true
}
```

Essa regra irá validar elementos seguindo a seguinte regra CSS `[name="media"]`, usando o método `verifica_media` passando para tal o argumento `true`. Como, pelo HTML, vemos que não há elementos com esse seletor não é feita a validação.

Para validar um conjunto de elementos baseado na classe, possibilitando que haja um número qualquer de elementos no formulário para serem validados, use o método customizado. Ao se criar um método com o mesmo nome da classe ele será aplicado aos elementos do formulário validado:

```
/* remova */ $.validator.addMethod("verifica_media", function(value, element) { 
/*    use */ $.validator.addMethod("conceito", function(value, element) {
```

Assim esse método será aplicada aos elementos `.conceito`, mas não somente essa alteração nele outra deve ser feita: ele, como foi escrito, verifica se qualquer `.Checkconceito` está marcada. Altere para que ele cheque o checkbox próprio `input` sendo validada.

```
/* remova */ $('.Checkconceito').is(":checked")
/*    use */ $(element).next().is(":checked")
```

Após essas alterações parece que todos os erros foram arrumados.

Comment: Obrigado pelo conhecimento cedido pela resposta.